# OpenOffice Writer default to Web Layout

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

Is there a way to get OpenOffice Writer to always open documents in Web Layout? Or, at least properly respect the view of the document? That is, if a document was in Web Layout when saved, then opening that document should be in Web Layout.

Comment: I think it is not possible (at least on a easy way), since layout is saved  with the document. There is something about it here: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=75415 . I tried to use command lines like 'start soffice -web "doc1.doc"', but it opens in saved layout, not in layout chosen in command line. Using "start soffice -web", it opens an empty document in web layout. You must search for an way to force opening in web layout or you must use macros...

Answer (score 0):

What platform did you try this on?

On my system (Debian Linux), if I set a document to "Web Layout", then save as ODT, it will open with Web Layout. Tried using OOo 3.2.0.

Did you maybe not save the document in OpenDocument (.odt) format?

Comment: Looks like you are correct, my document was saved in Word format. I do believe that Word documents do contain view information, maybe it's not OpenOffice compatible (Print vs Web Layout).

Comment: @Wavy Crab: Probably OOo does not use the view information saved by MS Word, either because it does not match the views that OOo has, or just because it was never implemented.